# Reopening modal dialog very slow on production server

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, modal-dialog

I have modal dialog boxes on my site.

They work perfectly on my development machine and my test server.

On the production server though, they work properly the first time they're opened, but if they're closed and reopened...

In Firefox they work perfectly.

In Chrome they spin for about 2 minutes, then open. They do this every time they're opened after the first time.

In IE they spin for about 2 minutes, then open. They do this every other time after.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is crumbling. They’ve apparently lost or destroyed their core competency. This is the umpteenth time they’ve had to pull a major patch that blue-screened Microsoft systems during the last 12 months.

Turns out my main application is now subject to this brand new bug on ALL MS IE browsers and there’s a specific hotfix for each DIFFERENT IE version on each DIFFERENT Microsoft OS, with separate versions for each of those in x86 and x64:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2991509

Oh, and you can apply the hoxfix only if one or more specific problematic updates have already been applied to the OS.

I have no idea how I could go about programmatically figuring all of that out and applying the right hoxfix on the many PCs my application runs on.

Microsoft is truly doomed when it reaches this point of complexity in trying to back-fix update problems of its own creation.